# Applying DropShadowFilter to text within mx.controls.TextInput component in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, filter, components, textinput

Is there a way to apply, say, a DropShadowFilter to the text within a TextInput component in Flex 3 without affecting the component itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your `mx.controls.TextInput` *does* have a member called `textField` of type IUITextField, but it is `protected`, so it can't be accessed directly from other classes.
You can view the source code for it in your Flex SDK under `/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/controls/TextInput.as`.

In order to modify this member, you can still do one of two things:

1. Create a class that extends `mx.controls.TextInput`.  Subclasses can access protected members, so you should be able to add your DropShadowFilter, probably best by overriding the `updateDisplayList` method.
2. Use the display list:

   ```
   for (var i:int = 0; i < myTextInput.numChildren; i++) {
       var child:DisplayObject = myTextInput.getChildAt(i);
       if (child is IUITextField) doStuffToTextField(child);
   }
   ```

Comment: I’m using TextInput from mx.controls package (and not from fl.controls). Unfortunately, my TextInput doesn’t have a textField property.

Comment: I have updated my answer. btw - adding the package information to your question would have made this a bit easier to answer ;)

Comment: You can also listen for ADDED_TO_STAGE in the TextInput and get a reference to the TextInput that way.